# Mongodb/mongoose omit a field in response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to use `projection` in mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields

```
var getUsers = function getUsers(callback, limit) {
    return _Schemas.User.find(callback).where('isVerified').equals(true).limit(limit)
                   .sort({ date: -1 }).project({ userEmail: 0 });
};
```

However, it returns error (and 500 response). If I remove `.project({ userEmail: 0 });` - **it works**. Note: There is `userEmail` in every collection.

Why it doesn't work if I keep `.project({ userEmail: 0 })`? Looking for help

Comment: With Mongoose, the Query method for this is called `select`, not `project`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You are helpful as always, thank you Johnny